# Flex 4 Spark BorderContainer - draw border for specific sides?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, border

Is there a way to easily specify on which sides a border is drawn for Flex 4's Spark BorderContainer?

I found this: http://forums.adobe.com/message/2956325

But that uses MX styling which seems like a hack.  Is there a better or 'correct' way without having to build a skin?  It seems incredibly silly to build a skin for a 'Bordered' component when this is a very common use case.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the spark components are designed to be lightweight, so I'm not surprised that BorderContainer doesn't have the same bells/whistles as its mx counterpart.  If I was in your situation I would create a simple skin that uses Lines instead of a border on each of the sides so you can configure the widths however you like.  Sounds like a hassle, but much of the flexibility of spark components is dependent upon creating custom skins.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Wade - it's really unfortunate IMO that something so common is not supported by the toolkit's default bordering component.  Creating a skin for such a thing sounds like a cumbersome solution for something so trivial.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to agree.  The lightweight spark components are a welcome change for the most part, but it seems there could have been some middle ground there somewhere with respect to basic functionality.